# ¿Còmo obtener permisos para editar un archivo con candadito en Ububtu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, autenticacion

¡Hola! recientemente me pasé a Linux Ubuntu... ejecuté `npm i- yarn` y luego `yarn create react-app miprimerapp`, sin embargo mi carpeta tiene un candadito que no me permite modificar mis archivos en VSC ni eliminar la carpeta, dice que tengo el acceso denegado.

Intenté con lo siguiente:

```
chown -R yeraldin:yeraldin /home/yeraldin/Documentos/GitHub/miprimerapp
```

No sé si tenga que ve,pero si coloco: `su` y luego mi contraseña me arroja un mensaje que dice "Fallo de autenticación", si coloco `sudo -i` y luego mi contraseña ya me sale root@yeraldin, pero desde root si pongo `cd Documentos` para seguir la ruta de mi carpeta me dice que no existe el archivo o directorio.

Gracias :)

Comment: prueba desde tu usuario ```yearldin``` con bajos privilegios a darle permisos como ```root``` de esta  manera ```chmod +x yeraldin:yeraldin```, aver si asi se puede solucionar.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias ejecute tal cual lo siguiente:                      **yeraldin@yeraldin-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~$** sudo -i
[sudo] contraseña para yeraldin: 
**root@yeraldin-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~#** sudo su chmod +x 777 yeraldin:yeraldin
su: el usuario chmod no existe
**root@yeraldin-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~# ** su yeraldin 
**yeraldin@yeraldin-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:/root$** sudo su chmod +x 777 yeraldin:yeraldin
su: el usuario chmod no existe
**yeraldin@yeraldin-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:/root$** cd Documentos 
bash: cd: Documentos: Permiso denegado

Comment: Intenta: `sudo su` y tu contraseña, luego `chmod +x yeraldin:yeraldin`

Comment: Gracias :) combinando sudo su ya aceptó la contraseña

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya has solucionado el problema paso a explicarte por qué daba esos fallos.

---

En primer lugar, en Linux, cuando creas un fichero, este pertenece a un usuario concreto, y tiene ciertos permisos de acceso tanto para el propietario como para otros usuarios.

Puedes ver los permisos que tienen los ficheros de un directorio si tecleas `ls -l`. Y verás algo como:

`-rw-r--r-- yeraldin yeraldin ... fichero`

Los puntos suspensivos significan que hay más información mostrada que no pongo aquí por simplicidad.

Información sobre permisos en Linux [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permisos_de_acceso_a_archivos).

Al no dejarte eliminar el directorio, se ve que no tenías permisos de escritura sobre el directorio y los ficheros, porque entre otras cosas pertenecían a otro usuario.

---

En segundo lugar, la orden `su` te permite iniciar sesión como otro usuario.

```
su pepe    // Inicia sesión como pepe
su         // Inicia sesión como root
```

Lo curioso es que la orden `su` te permite *loguearte* como tú misma, es decir puedes hacer:

`su yeraldin`

Y esto te permitirá iniciar sesión como tú misma (en una terminal donde ya hayas iniciado sesión como yeraldin).

El caso es que en Ubuntu, el usuario `root` no está habilitado, es decir, no puedes hacer un *login* directo mediante esta orden.

Esto no es un error, es la manera de funcionar normal en Ubuntu (y muchas otras distribuciones).

Por eso cuando ejecutabas `su` te daba error, porque `root` está deshabilitado.

---

Por otro lado, cada usuario que crees (sin especificar lo contrario) tiene un directorio propio bajo el directorio `/home`. Por tanto tu usuario `yeraldin` tiene un directorio personal llamado `/home/yeraldin`, y recuerda que la raíz del sistema de ficheros es `/`, de manera similar (pero no exactamente igual) a `C:/` en Windows.

Información sobre la jerarquía del sistema de ficheros [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Sin embargo, el usuario `root`, que es el administrador, tiene el directorio de trabajo `/root`.

Dicho esto, existe una lista con todos los usuarios normales a los que se les permite ejecutar ordenes con permisos de administración (llamados `sudoers`). Y lo hacen mediante la orden `sudo`.

```
sudo rm fichero.txt    // Elimina un fichero como si fueras root porque eres sudoer y te dejan
sudo su                // Inicia sesión como root aunque esté deshabilitado
```

Cuando ejecutas `sudo -i` lo que ocurre es que se intenta iniciar una sesión como `root`, ya que eres un `sudoer`, pero al mismo tiempo se cambia el directorio actual por el directorio del administrador.

Cabe destacar que los usuarios normales suelen tener varios directorios en su carpeta personal, entre los que está `Documentos`, pero el administrador no los tiene a menos que los crees tú a mano.

---

Finalmente, con todo lo dicho, se explica la solución a la que llegaste.

```
sudo su
chown -R yeraldin:yeraldin /home/yeraldin/Documentos/GitHub/miprimerapp
```

La orden `chown` te permite cambiar el propietario de un fichero o directorio, pero no puedes apropiarte de los ficheros y directorios de otro usuario, a menos que seas `root`, ya que es el administrador y tiene privilegios que no tienen otros usuarios.

Por eso es que hacía falta que ejecutes `sudo su` primero, porque te conviertes en administrador, y luego ya puedes cambiar el propietario del directorio que quieras.

También valdría:

```
sudo chown -R yeraldin:yeraldin /home/yeraldin/Documentos/GitHub/miprimerapp
```

Porque ejecuta la orden `chown` con privilegios de administración porque el sistema te lo permite mediante la orden `sudo`.

---

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y aclare un poco.

Comment: Muchas gracias  por la explicación, llevo tres días en ubuntu y me aclaraste muchas cosas. Yo instalé el SO desde un principio en la lap pero al parecer se me pasaron algunos detalles. Ya iré aprendiendo. Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: De nada! Estamos para ayudar. Pero recuerda que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de programación, por lo que si tienes más dudas relacionadas con la administración de Ubuntu te recomiendo que las resuelvas en [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), que también forma parte de la red _Stack Exchange_, al igual que este sitio web.

Comment: Gracias  buscaré ahí

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias :) hice una combinación de respuestas... aceptó la contraseña al poner:

`sudo su`

... y después

`chown -R yeraldin:yeraldin /home/yeraldin/Documentos/GitHub/miprimerapp`

y con eso eliminó el icono de candadito de la carpeta y ya me deja editarla, manipularla.

Muchas gracias :D